# Solr search part of the word

Tags: apache, solr

I am indexing data in Solr.
My search keyword is "tendulkar"

Then a word like sachintendulkar, Solr is unable to split it using any of the Tokenizer Factory.

I am familar with NGramFilterFactory.I dont want to use that.I just want the specific keyword to get filtered out from the lowercase word.

Can anyone help me out.

I am using this configuration:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeepWordFilterFactory" words="keepwords.txt" ignoreCase="true" enablePositionIncrements="false"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeepWordFilterFactory" words="keepwords.txt" ignoreCase="true" enablePositionIncrements="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [DictionaryCompoundTokenfilter](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_4_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/compound/DictionaryCompoundWordTokenFilterFactory.html)